# gaction test caller has no permission

Tags: raspberry-pi3, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to setup custom commands on my raspberry pi 3 with google assistant SDK. I was following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/custom-actions) to setup my custom command. Whenever I run `gactions test` ti would get the following error:

```
Pushing the app for the Assistant for testing...
ERROR: Failed to test the app for the Assistant
ERROR: The caller does not have permission
2019/05/16 17:50:23 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

I have used `gactions update` to upload my action definition json file, with the google account that owns the Google Action project, and it was updated successfully. Therefore I'm not sure why I would have no permission on a project I owned and with a successfully updated action json.

There is the json I had for my custom action.

```
{
  "manifest": {
      "displayName": "DJ Roomba",
      "invocationName": "DJ Roomba",
      "category": "PRODUCTIVITY"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Thanos Snap",
      "name": "djroomba.name.ThanosSnap",
      "availability": {
          "deviceClasses": [
              {
                  "assistantSdkDevice": {}
              }
          ]
      },
      "fulfillment": {
        "staticFulfillment": {
            "templatedResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "You should have gone for the head"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "deviceExecution": {
                            "command": "action.devices.commands.ThanosSnap"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "djroomba.intent.ThanosSnap",
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "Thanos snap"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "locale": "en"
}
```

I'm not sure if this will help, but I'm using Raspbian Jessie(since snowboy only supports up to that)

Comment: I don't believe the issue is related to the action package, but rather you may need to check which account is signed into gactions. It may help to logout and login to the tool again to make sure it's on the right Google account.

Comment: @NickFelker I was logging in with the account owning the action project, or do I need to use a seperate account?

Comment: gactions should be logged into the same account as your project

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out to be that I'll have to at least publish my action in alpha or beta version, otherwise the `gactions test` will not work